# VB.net sending integer via bluetooth

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth, send, lego-mindstorms

Firstly sorry for asking this again, I know there are already articles about that but any of them worked.

I've a lego mindstorms and I want to send and receive integer from it via bluetooth.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Normally Bluetooth should function as a COM port (RS232) so it should function as a Serialport. If you have a bluetooth dongle conected you can go into your device manager search your Bluetooth dongle

I hope this SS works :-s

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNNGj.png

after you have found it you can open it trough a serial port in VB.net and you should be able to send string through this to your BT receiver.

However, your BT modules need to be connected to each other, so make sure you are setting up everything through the serial communication

I hope this helped, since I don't know what you already know/don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I couldn't find any working projects on internet neighter about sending and receiving via serialport.

Comment: Well, If you know the basic of your specific module, It shouldn't be hard to do, any serial terminal will do, you just need to select the right COM port (the port assigned to your BT "host") to send the data from

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work the program stoped working(there wasn't even an error message).